# Unable to add kubernetes-bionic main (Ubuntu 18.04) to apt repository

Tags: kubernetes, apt, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install Kubernetes on my Ubuntu server/desktop version 18.04.1. 
But, when I want to add kubernetes to the apt repository using the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-bionic main"
```

I get the following error:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                               
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                          
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                            
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                       
Ign:8 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-bionic InRelease                              
Err:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.211.110 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

If I then try to install `kubeadm`, it does not work because I don't have the repository added to apt

I hope someone can shed some light on my issue..

All of this is running inside a VM on Hyper-V

PS: I'm not a die hard Linux expert but coming from Windows!

Comment: Have you downloaded the gpg and added it to apt-key?

Comment: @Crou yes i have..

Comment: At the moment i manually added `kubernetes.list` to `/ect/apt/sources.list.d/` and added `[allow-insecure=yes]` this fixes my problem for now but it's not the preferred way i think.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk the error message is "kubernetes-bionic Release' does not have a Release file." this has nothing to do with validation errors. as you can see at https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists there are no metadata files for bionic, thus no packages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment (nov. 2018) there is no bionic folder. You can see the supported distributions here:

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists

The last kubernetes version there is: kubernetes-yakkety

This should still work with bionic.

Comment: Still none in 2021. Only `kubernetes-xenial` worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 9):

Bionic folder is still not yet created however I tested with adding repository with '
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" and 
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-yakkety main"

I am able to install Kubeadm, Kubectl & kubelet on Ubuntu 18.04 with codename *bionic**....

Please make sure to add GPG key as it is recommended & good practice to follow otherwise this creates vulnerability to push malicious code through proper package name...

```
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add
```

You can check by yourself what all repository are present on dists - https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/

You can also verify whether the repository has been added to /etc/apt/source.list or /etc/apt/source.list.d, if it is there then you should be fine....